# PHP & XML Creation: Node in wrong parent

Tags: php, xml, oop, soap, domdocument

I am working currently on an OOP based PHP project in MVC style.
For my project i need to create/send/recieve/process XMLs.

Now i have a BIG problem with creating XML-Structures with **DOMDocument**.
Everytime i create a new XML-Node without an **attributes** or **values**, all nodes afterwards will be a child if this node!

**In other words:** I can not create an **empty XML-Node** without all nodes afterwards beeing a child of **this empty node**!!!

This problem bugs me for while now but I really need the way I am dealing right now with the XML creation.
I couldn't find any solutions but some similar problems.

This PHP tests my XmlHandler-Class, which creates the XML-Request:

**Test.php:**

```
<?php

include "Handler/XmlHandler.php";


$xmlHandler=new XmlHandler();

$xmlHandler->CreateNewXmlInstance();
$root = $xmlHandler->CreateRootNode('RootNode');
$l1 = $xmlHandler->AppendNodeWithChild($root, "NodeLevel1", "Text1 - This node one has text");
$l2 = $xmlHandler->AppendNodeWithChild($root, "NodeLevel2", "Text2 - Next node Level3 level is not gonna have text");
$l21 = $xmlHandler->AppendNodeWithChild($l2, "NodeLevel2_1", "Text2_1 - This node will be a child of Level2, everything fine");
$l3 = $xmlHandler->AppendNodeWithChild($root, "NodeLevel3", "");
$l4 = $xmlHandler->AppendNodeWithChild($root, "NodeLevel4", "Text4 - This node should be on same level like 3, 2 & 1, but instead it's a child of Level 3 (?!?!?!?!)");

echo "<p style='display:none;'>".$xmlHandler->SaveXml()."</p>";

?>
```

Here is the XML-Handler Class which i use to create the XML-Request-Structure (i just posted the neccessary parts of the class here)

**XmlHandler.php:**

```
<?php 

class XmlHandler{


    private $xml;

    /**
     *
     *    Constructor
     *
     */

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->xml=null;

    }

    //[...]

    /*
    *   Custom XML-Creator Functions 
    *
    */

    public function CreateNewXmlInstance(){
        /*********************************************/
        /** XML DOM example of building XML Request **/
        /*********************************************/
        $this->xml = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
        return $this->xml;
    }

    public function CreateRootNode($name){
        $rootElement = $this->xml->appendChild( $this->xml->createElement($name) );
        return $rootElement;
    }

    public function AppendNodeWithChild($node, $childName, $childText){
        $result = $node->appendChild($this->xml->createElement($childName));
        if(null != $childText && !empty($childText)){
            $result->appendChild( $this->xml->createTextNode($childText) );
        }

        return $result;
    }

    public function SetNodeAttributes($node, $nameAndValues){
        if(null != $nameAndValues && sizeof($nameAndValues) > 0){
            foreach($nameAndValues as $name => $value){
                $this->SetNodeAttribute($node, $name, $value);
            }
        }
    }

    public function SetNodeAttribute($node, $name, $value){
        $node->setAttribute($name, $value);
    }

    public function SaveXml(){
        return $this->xml->saveXML();
    }

    //[...]

}

?>
```

**This is the Result:**

```
<!-- ?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"? -->
<rootnode>
    <nodelevel1>Text1 - This node one has text</nodelevel1>
    <nodelevel2>Text2 - Next node Level3 level is not gonna have text
        <nodelevel2_1>Text2_1 - This node will be a child of Level2, everything fine</nodelevel2_1>
    </nodelevel2>
    <nodelevel3>
        <nodelevel4>Text4 - This node should be on same level like 3, 2 &amp; 1, but instead it's a child of Level 3 (?!?!?!?!)</nodelevel4>
    </nodelevel3>
</rootnode>
```

**But in theory, there should be somethign like that:**

```
<!-- ?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"? -->
<rootnode>
    <nodelevel1>Text1 - This node one has text</nodelevel1>
    <nodelevel2>Text2 - Next node Level3 level is not gonna have text
        <nodelevel2_1>Text2_1 - This node will be a child of Level2, everything fine</nodelevel2_1>
    </nodelevel2>
    <nodelevel3/>
    <nodelevel4>Text4 - This node should be on same level like 3, 2 &amp; 1, but instead it's a child of Level 3 (?!?!?!?!)</nodelevel4>
</rootnode>
```

As you can see: Something went wrong when i had not set a value for the new created Node on Level3!:

```
$l3 = $xmlHandler->AppendNodeWithChild($root, "NodeLevel3", "");
$l4 = $xmlHandler->AppendNodeWithChild($root, "NodeLevel4", "Text4 - This node should be on same level like 3, 2 & 1, but instead it's a child of Level 3 (?!?!?!?!)");
```

As long as i set attributes or put in value sin the new created node, everything is fine.
But i have some situations where also pure empty nodes have to be created!

**My question is:**

What am I doing wrong here?

Or does PHP do something wrong?

Maybe my browser does a bad preparation of the XML, but the outgoing XML request was build and send correctly and the mistake lies something else?

If so, how can I check the XML request though?

**Edit Nr.2:**

I changed my question/original post somehow.
The above example is a bit more easy to understand.
At least i hope so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok guys, somebody helped me with this problem.
Here is the conversation:

**Him:** The tags are wrong (since they've been changed to all-lowercase)

**Me:** Yes, it seems the XML gets messy after **echoing** it out **into the browser** instead of saving it **into a file**!

**Him:** And the output shouldn't even be formatted

**Me:** I did that myself for a better view

**Him:** This is the raw output of $xmlHandler->SaveXml() after enabling formatted output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RootNode>
  <NodeLevel1>Text1 - This node one has text</NodeLevel1>
  <NodeLevel2>Text2 - Next node Level3 level is not gonna have text<NodeLevel2_1>Text2_1 - This node will be a child of Level2, everything fine</NodeLevel2_1></NodeLevel2>
  <NodeLevel3/>
  <NodeLevel4>Text4 - This node should be on same level like 3, 2 &amp; 1, but instead it's a child of Level 3 (?!?!?!?!)</NodeLevel4>
</RootNode>
```

**Me:** After **printing** it out into a **file**, i got the same result as you.

**The conclusion:**

Now I've wrote the saveXml-output into a file.
The Result is he same as **Him** told me.

**So were was the mess?**

I thoght it would be enough to print the XML out into the browser with **echo** and check it through the HTML-sourcecode via FireFox.

As you can see in my first post, i used echo...

```
echo "<p style='display:none;'>".$xmlHandler->SaveXml()."</p>";
```

to somehow print out the result of my XML-Creation (because i didn't know how else).

Therefore the XML-Creation was a full success from start up and the error i get from the response-Server lies somewhere else (from now on i can not rely on your help anymore)!

Answer (score 0):

**Wrap your helper functions in a class**

```
class XMLHelper {
    /*
    *   Custom XML-Creator Functions
    *
    */

    private $xml;

    public function CreateNewXmlInstance(){
        /*********************************************/
        /** XML DOM example of building XML Request **/
        /*********************************************/
        $this->xml = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
        return $this->xml;
    }

    public function CreateRootNode($name){
        $rootElement = $this->xml->appendChild( $this->xml->createElement($name) );
        return $rootElement;
    }

    public function AppendNodeWithChild($node, $childName, $childText){
        $result = $node->appendChild($this->xml->createElement($childName));
        if(null != $childText && !empty($childText)){
            $result->appendChild( $this->xml->createTextNode($childText) );
        }

        return $result;
    }

    public function SetNodeAttributes($node, $nameAndValues){
        if(null != $nameAndValues && sizeof($nameAndValues) > 0){
            foreach($nameAndValues as $name => $value){
                $this->SetNodeAttribute($node, $name, $value);
            }
        }
    }

    public function SetNodeAttribute($node, $name, $value){
        $node->setAttribute($name, $value);
    }

    public function SaveXml(){
        return $this->xml->saveXML();
    }
}
```

Wrap things in class because your code contain `$this` calls

Wrapping things in class make `$this` calls to correct variables the program needs.

**Then new the class and initialize the nodes**

```
$test = new XMLHelper();
$test->CreateNewXmlInstance();
$request = $test->CreateRootNode("request");
$node1 = $test->AppendNodeWithChild($request, "node1", null);
$node2 = $test->AppendNodeWithChild($node1, "node2", null);
$test->SetNodeAttributes($node2, array(
    "client" => "This is a testing value"
));

echo $test->saveXml();

//Output: 
//    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
//    <request>
//        <node1>
//            <node2 client="This is a testing value"/>
//        </node1>
//    </request>
```

Please be noted that code need to executed in a correct sequence.

1. New the root node ( request )
2. Then append a node 1 to ( request )
3. Finally append node 2 to node 1
4. Configure the client value of node 2
5. **Print out the whole root node**
6. Then you've done the magic

There is nothing wrong with PHP neither with your web browser.

The error probably come from you haven't initialize the root node and not adding the created node correctly to the **root node**.

For XML validation in php, see [this link](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.validate.php).

DOMDocument has a function built-in for validation.

**Edit 2016-08-10**

Here are the revised code of your case

```
class SpecificXmlHandler extends XmlHandler{

    /**
     *    Constructor
     *
     */

    private $errorCounter;
    private $xmlUrl;

    //Declare the root first
    private $root;

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->errorCounter=0;
        $this->xmlUrl=Configuration::XML_REQUEST_URL;
    }


    //[...]

    /**
     *   Action Functions
     */

    public function GetStaticData($requestName, $requestFilterNamesAndValues){
        $xml = $this->BuildStaticDataRequest($requestName, $requestFilterNamesAndValues);
        echo "<p style='display:none'>" . $xml. "</p>";     //Request
        $response = $this->ExecuteRequest($this->xmlUrl, $xml, null, false);
        echo "<p style='display:none'>" . $response . "</p>"; //Resonse

        //[...]
    }

    //[...]

    /**
    *   Request Building Functions
    */

    public function BuildStaticDataRequest($requestName, $requestFilterNamesAndValues){

        $this->CreateNewXmlInstance();
        //$root = $this->CreateRootNode('Request');
        //Use the root node you have created in the constructor by using $this
        $this->root = $this->CreateRootNode('Request');
        //Generate Header (Source-Node)
        $this->GenerateHeadData($this->root);

        //[...]

        return $this->SaveXml();
    }

    public function GenerateHeadData($root){

        $clientID=Configuration::XML_CLIENT;


        //Here the Node1 & Node2 creation
        $node1 = $this->AppendNodeWithChild($root, "node1", null);
        $node2 = $this->AppendNodeWithChild($node1, "node2", null);

        $this->SetNodeAttributes( $node2 , array(
            "Client" =>$clientID
        ));

        //Change it to return the whole root
        return $root;

    }

[...]


}
```

Please create variables in the class and use `$this` to refer the private variables you have created.

Comment: Hello MiKeNeko and thank you for your response.
My code is already like you described it in your answer.
Like i said, i am developing **OOP**.

But still i get the problem with node2 not in node1.

Comment: I have added more of my classes-code in my original post. I can't tell where the error is.
Your steps are:

`New the root node ( request ) //CHECK

Then append a node 1 to ( request ) //CHECK

Finally append node 2 to node 1 //CHECK

Configure the client value of node 2 //CHECK

Print out the whole root node //CHECK

Then you've done the magic //CHECK`


Or am i missing something?

Comment: I have make a update to the answer see if it helps.
I think you have just miss out a `$this`.
Please see my updated code.

Comment: Hello again. Thank you for your help, but there is no reason why changing the **local $root** variable into a **global** one. I found the reason i guess, but i do not know why it happens. Please, see my edited post above for more. As you will see, the main reason are nodes which get created without any **values** or **attributes** (empty node)!